Find local password with PowerShell
I have to set up Scan To Folder.
To avoid having to:
Create a Scanner user with the password "example123" on Windows
Switch the network from public to private
Create a folder in the documents and manage sharing permissions
Enable SMB 1.0 on Windows
Access the web interface of my printer and navigate to the address book to add a new user and paste the path of the folder in my documents
I have done all of this from a PowerShell script. To prevent error messages when creating a Scanner user if one already exists, I want to check if the already created user has the correct password. If not, create Scanner2.
Write-Host @"
 ____  ____  ____                  ____  _____     _     _           
' ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
' //                                                                        //
' //  ____  ____  ____                  ____  _____     _     _             //
' // |  _ \|  _ \/ ___|  ___ __ _ _ __ |___ \|  ___|__ | | __| | ___ _ __   //
' // | | | | | | \___ \ / __/ _` | '_ \  __) | |_ / _ \| |/ _` |/ _ \ '__|  //
' // | |_| | |_| |___) | (_| (_| | | | |/ __/|  _| (_) | | (_| |  __/ |     //
' // |____/|____/|____/ \___\__,_|_| |_|_____|_|  \___/|_|\__,_|\___|_|     //
' //                                                                        //
' ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
"@
                
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Force

$userName = Read-Host "Display name in address book: "

Write-Host "Here are the available printers with their IP addresses"
$printers = Get-Printer
$printerInfo = @()
foreach ($printer in $printers) {
    $printerName = $printer.Name
    $portName = $printer.PortName
    if ($portName -match 'IP_(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})') {
        $ipAddress = $Matches[1]
        $printerInfo += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            "Printer Name" = $printerName
            "IP Address" = $ipAddress
        }
    }
}
$printerInfo | Format-Table -AutoSize
Write-Host "If your printer is not listed, please go to google.com."
$printerIP = Read-Host "Enter the IP address of the printer where you want to add ${userName} to the address book: "

if ($printerIP -match '\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}') {
    $userExists = Get-LocalUser -Name "Scanner" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    if ($userExists -and (Test-Path "C:\Users\Scanner") -and (net user Scanner | Select-String -SimpleMatch "Example123")) {
        Write-Host "The 'Scanner' user already exists, and its password is 'Example123'."
    } elseif ($userExists -and (Test-Path "C:\Users\Scanner")) {
        Write-Host "The 'Scanner' user already exists, but its password is not 'Example123'."
        $password = ConvertTo-SecureString "Example123" -AsPlainText -Force
        New-LocalUser -Name "Scanner2" -Password $password -FullName "Scanner2" -Description "Backup account for the scanner"
        $folderScanAccount = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList "Scanner2", $password
    } elseif (!$userExists) {
        $password = ConvertTo-SecureString "Example123" -AsPlainText -Force
        New-LocalUser -Name "Scanner" -Password $password -FullName "Scanner" -Description "Account for the scanner"
        $folderScanAccount = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList "Scanner", $password
    }

    if ($folderScanAccount) {
        Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName SMB1Protocol -NoRestart
        Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName SMB1Protocol-Client -NoRestart
        Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName SMB1Protocol-Deprecation -NoRestart
        Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update" -Name "RebootRequired" -Value 0 -Force

        $connectionProfiles = Get-NetConnectionProfile

        foreach ($profile in $connectionProfiles) {
            if ($profile.NetworkCategory -eq "Public" -and ($profile.InterfaceAlias -like "*Wi-Fi*" -or $profile.InterfaceAlias -like "*Ethernet*")) {
                Set-NetConnectionProfile -InterfaceIndex $profile.InterfaceIndex -NetworkCategory Private
                Write-Host "The $($profile.InterfaceAlias) profile has been changed to private."
            }
        }

        Write-Host "All Wi-Fi and Ethernet profiles have been changed to private, if applicable."

        $share_name = "Scanner"
        $user_documents = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("MyDocuments")
        $path = Join-Path $user_documents "Scanner"

        if (!(Get-SmbShare | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $share_name })) {
            if (!(Test-Path -Path $path -PathType Container)) {
                New-Item -Path $path -ItemType Directory
            }

            net share $share_name=$path /grant:"Scanner,FULL" /remark:"Shared for Scanner"
            icacls $path /grant "Scanner:(OI)(CI)RW" /inheritance:e /t
        }

        if (Get-SmbShare | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $share_name }) {
            Write-Output "$share_name has been successfully shared."

            $UNCPath = "\\$env:COMPUTERNAME\$share_name"

            Install-Module -Name RicohAddressBook

            Add-AddressBookEntry -Hostname $printerIP -Credential $credential -Name $userName -KeyDisplay $userName -Title1 "AB" -FolderScanPath $UNCPath -FolderScanAccount $folderScanAccount
        } else {
            Write-Output "Sharing $share_name failed."
        }
    }
} else {
    Write-Host "The entered IP address is not valid."
}

Read-Host "Press Enter t


When a Scanner user with the good password is already created. It creates Scanner2 anyway


Well, I thought I understood that it wasn't so easy to recover a user's password in plaintext. Is it possible to try logging into the Scanner session with the password 'example123'? And if that doesn't work, it's probably not the right password, so create Scanner2?

Please consider trimming down your runnable example to illustrate only the part you are having issues with. I.e. it's hard to know what part you want some help with.

Instead of trying to start a big process such as PowerShell as in the example of @T-Me, I always go for rdpclip.exe instead as it's very light weight and then catches any errors.
try {
  start-process rdpclip.exe -Credential $Credentials
}
catch {
  throw $_.Exception.Message
}


Thank you very much for your help! I just tried your method and it works, I will use your method since it is lighter than the other one :)

Remember to mark your question as solved once you have a working solution.

I don't know why they hated you so much. However, your question could use a few dots and commas.
You won't get the password from net user Scanner. It is not stored in plain text. Instead you could try to start a process as the user, to check if it has the password you know.
Create a credential object from the [SecureString] you already have and use it in a Start-Process. If it fails, the password was not correct (or you don't have the permission to start a process. Test it first without -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
$credentials = [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]::new("$env:COMPUTERNAME\Scanner",$password)    
$TestShell = Start-Process powershell.exe -Credential $credentials -ArgumentList '-command "exit"' -PassThru -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if($TestShell){'yay I know the password'}

